# Datatable Select() Method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a Datagridview and the `Data Source` is `dtCustomer`
I just want to filter the content of grid view based on a search text.
   Itried the following code

```
DataTable dtSearch =  dtCustomer;
dtSearch.Select("cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'");
grvCustomer.DataSource = dtSearch;
```

But this is not working.
If any body knows the solution please share.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
dtSearch.DefaultView.RowFilter = "cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
```

And check whatever there is space to be removed by triming the text.

Answer (score 8):

The return value for [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) is a DataRow[] array.  It returns a list of matching DataRows.  Your code does nothing with those rows at the moment.

You can setup a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) with a filter and set the grid's DataSource to the DataView:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtSearch);
dv.RowFilter = "...";
grvCustomer.DataSource = dv;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01s96x0z.aspx) (code not tested) -

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtSearch);
dv.RowFilter = "cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
grvCustomer.DataSource = dv;
```

Answer (score 3):

Or Try this;

```
dataGridView.Datasource = datatable.Select("....").CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dtCustomer.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(dr => (string)dr["cust_Name"].Startswith("zzz")).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
DataView dv1 = dtDefault.DefaultView; 
dv1.RowFilter = "CusGroupId=1 and CustomerCode LIKE '"+txtCustomer.Text +"%'";  
DataTable dt=dv1.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTable.Select returns array of row, but you are binding entire data table not filtered rows. use this way or `DataView`

```
DataTable dtSearch =  dtCustomer;
var filter = dtSearch.Select("cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'");
grvCustomer.DataSource = filter.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
//DataTable dtSearch =  dtCustomer;
//dtSearch.Select("cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'");


grvCustomer.DataSource = dtCustomer.Select("cust_Name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'");
```

And when you want to go back to the original data

```
grvCustomer.DataSource = dtCustomer;
```