# Simplest/fastest way to check if value exists in DataTable in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` (currently with multiple columns but I could just grab one column if it makes it easier). I want to check if a `String` value exists in a column of the `DataTable`. (I'm doing it many times so I want it to be reasonably fast.)

What is a good way to do this? Iterating through the `DataTable` rows each time seems like a bad way. Can I convert the column to a flat `List/Array` format, and use a built in function? Something like `myStrList.Contains("value")`?

Comment: Are you searching the same, unchanging, DataTable many times?  If so, it would likely be faster to get the data into some kind of indexed data structure, such as a hash table, a tree, or a sorted array (for a binary search).  If, however, the data in the table keeps changing, you'd have to keep rebuilding your index which would make it worthless.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yes the DT doesn't change once it's fetched. Do you have an example of using a hash table/sorted array? The data would just be a list of strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the data in your `DataTable` doesn't change very often, and you search the `DataTable` multiple times, and your `DataTable` contains many rows, then it's likely going to be a lot faster to build your own index for the data.

The simplest way to do this is to sort the data by the key column so that you can then do a binary search on the sorted list.  For instance, you can build an index like this:

```
Private Function BuildIndex(table As DataTable, keyColumnIndex As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim index As New List(Of String)(table.Rows.Count)
    For Each row As DataRow in table.Rows
        index.Add(row(keyColumnIndex))
    Next
    index.Sort()
    Return index
End Function
```

Then, you can check if a value exists in the index quickly with a binary search, like this:

```
Private Function ItemExists(index As List(Of String), key As String) As Boolean
    Dim index As Integer = index.BinarySearch(key)
    If index >= 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

You could also do the same thing with a simple string array.  Or, you could use a `Dictionary` object (which is an implementation of a hash table) to build a hash index of your `DataTable`, for instance:

```
Private Function BuildIndex(table As DataTable, keyColumnIndex As Integer) As Dictionary(Of String, DataRow)
    Dim index As New Dictionary(Of String, DataRow)(table.Rows.Count)
    For Each row As DataRow in table.Rows
        index(row(keyColumnIndex)) = row
    Next
    Return index
End Function
```

Then, you can get the matching `DataRow` for a given key, like this:

```
Dim index As Dictionary(Of String, DataRow) = BuildIndex(myDataTable, myKeyColumnIndex)
Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
If index.TryGetValue(myKey, row) Then
   ' row was found, can now use row variable to access all the data in that row
Else
   ' row with that key does not exist
End If
```

You may also want to look into using either the `SortedList` or `SortedDictionary` class.  Both of these are implementations of binary trees.  It's hard to say which of all of these options is going to be fastest in your particular scenario.  It all depends on the type of data, how often the index needs to be re-built, how often you search it, how many rows are in the `DataTable`, and what you need to do with the found items.  The best thing to do would be to try each one in a test case and see which one works best for what you need.

Comment: Thanks, the `SortedList` works great. For some reason the standard `List` just didn't work - it kept returning negative indexes even when the string was in the list.

Comment: How would you solve the problem with table updates (rows being added/removed)?

Comment: When you do that, you need to either re-generate your index, or you need to make the same change to the index.  So, for instance, when a new row is added, you would need to add it to both the DataTable and the index, or just regenerate the whole index once the row has been added.

Comment: Regenerating the whole index may be time consuming, especially for large tables. If you go with index updates, how much more code do you have to write?

Comment: Yes, re-generating the index would definitely be slower.  That's hard to answer without knowing all the specifics of what you are doing.  One further thing to consider, however, is: do you need to actually do all of this in a disconnected `DataTable`?  If you have a connection to the DB, you will likely find that simply re-querying the DB is faster.  The DB, presumably, already has all of the necessary indices, so you wouldn't need to generate an in-memory index yourself.

Comment: See this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825034/search-and-replace-inside-string-column-in-datatable-is-slow). I have about 90k rows in a datatable, and for a given string-based column (with one word in each row) there's typically about 20-30 unique words in the entire column.  These 20-30 words need to be replaced with 20-30 other words.   IsDBNull also has to be checked when replacing.  It works out that .Select and LINQ to do this for 90k rows is not very fast(?)

Answer (score 24):

You can use `select` to find whether that value exist or not. If so, it returns rows or it will not. Here is some sample code to help you.

```
Dim foundRow() As DataRow
foundRow = dt.Select("SalesCategory='HP'")
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use [row filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836037/datatable-select-method) or [DataTable.Rows.Find()](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/33514) instead of select ([select does not use indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx)). Depending on your table structure, specifically *if your field in question is indexed* (locally), performance of either way should be much faster than looping through all rows. In .NET, a set of fields needs to be a [PrimaryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx) to become indexed.

If your field is not indexed, I would avoid both select and row filter, because aside from overhead of class complexity, they don't offer compile time check for correctness of your condition. If it's a long one, you may end up spending lots of time debugging it once in a while.

It is always preferable to have your check strictly typed. Having first defined an underlying type, you can also define this helper method, which you can convert to extension method of `DataTable` class later:

```
Shared Function CheckValue(myTable As DataTable, columnName As String, searchValue As String) As Boolean
  For row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    If row(columnName) = searchValue Then Return True
  Next
  Return False
End Function
```

or a more generic version of it:

```
Shared Function CheckValue(myTable As DataTable, checkFunc As Func(Of DataRow, Boolean)) As Boolean
  For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    If checkFunc(row) Then Return True
  Next
  Return False
End Function
```

and its usage:

```
CheckValue(myTable, Function(x) x("myColumn") = "123")
```

If your row class has `MyColumn` property of type `String`, it becomes:

```
CheckValue(myTable, Function(x) x.myColumn = "123")
```

One of the benefits of above approach is that you are able to feed calculated fields into your check condition, since `myColumn` here does not need to match a physical `myColumn` in the table/database.

Comment: You could also use `AsEnumerable()` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)) and the `Any()` method.

Comment: Is there any way to search the row for a pair of values? That is to say where col2 = "somestring" and col3 = an integer?

Comment: @htm11h: Yes, just apply a different function, i.e. `Function(x) x.col2 = "somestring" and x.col3 = 123`

Comment: I have found it is much faster to call `DataTable.Select` repeatedly after creating a `DataView` with a sort based on my search criteria.  This leads me to believe that the `DataTable.Select` will use an index if created by a `DataView`.

Comment: What if i wanted to use this but to find a value that is LIKE a string?  would it be CheckValue(myTable, Function(x) x("myColumn") like  "somevaluehere") or CheckValue(myTable, Function(x) x("myColumn") = "*somevaluehere") ?

Comment: @Pr0x1mo: Please use "Ask Question" button at the top to ask a new question.

Comment: 'For each' is the correct loop statement not just 'For'

Answer (score 0):

```
bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string>("Author").Equals("your lookup value")).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: This checks if the column author has the value "your lookup value" in any of the rows in datatable