# TextBox value equals with value from a database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Northwind database and when i want to change or put a new name at a textbox where the names of the ships are, my program to check all the names that already exist in the database and if there is not this name then to show me a message. I created a new table with only the ship names with fill and get commands. I don't know where is my mistake on the code.

```
Private Sub ShipNameTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ShipNameTextBox.Validating
    For i As Integer = 0 To NorthwindDataSet.Orders1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not (ShipNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(NorthwindDataSet.Orders1.Rows(i))) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The boat name should be one of the list")
            ShipNameTextBox.Focus()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Convert.ToString(NorthwindDataSet.Orders1.Rows(i).Columns(????)))  - You may indicate the columns to test. If you check this line with debugger you can view that the code "Convert.ToString(NorthwindDataSet.Orders1.Rows(i)))" return an object type (DataRow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest/fastest way to check if value exists in DataTable in VB.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444207/simplest-fastest-way-to-check-if-value-exists-in-datatable-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataTable `Select()` method like below which will return a `DataRow[]` (assuming that your datatable have a column name `shipname`)

```
DataRow[] rows = NorthwindDataSet.Orders1.Select("shipname = " + ShipNameTextBox.Text.Trim())
```

Then you can just check if the returned `DataRow` array has any rows. If filter condition doesn't match them it will be empty

```
if(rows.Length > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("The boat name should be one of the list")
   ShipNameTextBox.Focus()
}
```

Comment: And after this to compare this DataRow with my textbox?

Comment: Just check if the returned `DataRow[]` have any content then show your meesagebox. See edit in answer if that helps.