# Search and replace inside string column in DataTable is slow?

Tags: vb.net, search, replace, datatable

I am fetching distinct words in a string column of a DataTable (.dt) and then replacing the unique values with another value, so essentially changing words to other words.  Both approaches listed below work, however, for 90k records, the process is not very fast.  Is there a way to speed up either approach?

The first approach, is as follows:

```
   'fldNo is column number in dt
   For Each Word As String In DistinctWordList
      Dim myRow() As DataRow
      myRow = dt.Select(MyColumnName & "='" & Word & "'")
      For Each row In myRow
         row(fldNo) = dicNewWords(Word)
      Next
   Next
```

A second LINQ-based approach is as follows, and is actually not very fast either:

```
   Dim flds as new List(of String)
   flds.Add(myColumnName)
   For Each Word As String In DistinctWordsList
     Dim rowData() As DataRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(f) flds.Where(Function(el) f(el) IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso f(el).ToString = Word).Count = flds.Count).ToArray
     ReDim foundrecs(rowData.Count)
     Cnt = 0
     For Each row As DataRow In rowData
       Dim Index As Integer = dt.Rows.IndexOf(row)
       foundrecs(Cnt) = Index + 1 'row.RowId
       Cnt += 1
     Next
     For i = 0 To Cnt
       dt(foundrecs(i))(fldNo) = dicNewWords(Word)
     Next 
   Next
```

Comment: Define "not very fast"? I'm not surprised LINQ is "actually not very fast" - LINQ is more about brevity, not efficiency

Comment: Also, can you define your problem more simply? Your problem is hard to understand. it sounds like "I have a list of 90k words, some of which occur more than once and some of which occur only once. For those that occur only once, I want to swap them out for a different word that I have in a dictionary lookup already. The 90k words are in a column of a 90k row datatable, one word per row " - is it right?

Comment: @Caius Jard - "there are 90k records" in dt, not 90k words.   Also, the list of distinct words already found in this column is given by DistintWordsList, which was constructed using LINQ's .Distinct().  Your concern over "some words may occur once or more than once" doesn't matter, since unique words are unique words - if a word occurs once or more than once it is still unique.  No - not one word per row, many words are repeated - hence the term unique.  The example would be like 1 million records with names of car manufacturers - resulting in maybe 20 or 30 unique manufacturer names.

Comment: So, I'm still not really clear what you want to do. It now sounds like: You have 90k records. Each record has, say, an entire document with it (let's say a hundred words, a tweet, a short story, whatever). You have a dictionary of N replacements eg "foo"->"bar". You want to perform the replacements in all 90k documents ?  I'm trying to get you to better explain your problem; you know what your problem is because you can see it, but you haven't shown it to us nor done a great job of explaining it. Example data, and the output you're expecting (edited into your question) would help

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  A record only holds a single word, and many records have the same word, and there may be 20 unique words in the column. The intent is to basically replace each unique word with a different word.

Comment: It just seems that LINQ and .Select -->ToList(), approaches, which need to loop through each row as DataRow in the dt to make changes take a long time.   My gut feeling is that a SQL command like REPLACE might be faster.  Is there not a way to search and replace in a DataTable without looping? That's what a SQL command would do. Question is, what would the SQLQueryBuilder look like for a dt, and what would the SQL REPLACE commands look like?

Comment: Ok, so I now don't understand your question as: "I have a datatable with 90k rows. In one column there is a single word. The word needs swapping for another word. I have the swaps in a dictionary. There may be multiple occurrences of a particular word in the column and all occurrences must be swapped for the same word. For example the word "foo" might occur on 102 rows out of the 90k and all "foo" must become "bar". - if this is the case I don't get why you're selecting anything out of the datatable at all; I would just iterate it once and perform the swaps. SQL REPLACE would be worse

Comment: *Is there not a way to search and replace in a DataTable without looping?* - yes, but how will it help? What will you do with your datatable in the end?

Comment: "In one column there is a single word". Don't you mean: in one row (record) there is a single word, like I said?  The first approach (code) listed in the OP is painfully slow for e.g. 90k records.  LINQ doesn't really matter.   Is there a faster way to loop through the rows in a column to find "foo" and replace with "bar"?  Maybe a dataview?  The LINQ AsEnumerable() in the second approach (OP) builds a list of DataRow, and is fast for finding rows, so I need a fast way to replace.

Comment: "yes, but how will it help? What will you do with your datatable in the end"  I'm thinking there is an internal kernel behind the scenes for rapidly handling datatables the same way SQL rapidly processes queries in an ADO construct (OLEDB, SQLOLEDB, ODBC).  How will it help -- speed.  In the end, datatable values will be changed, doesn't matter what will happen to the datatable -- the OP is about search and replace.

Comment: I ask what will happen in the end because if you're looking at shaving off a few milliseconds you could subclass a data row so that it has a set of replacements in a built in dictionary that it returns when queried for a particular value - the values are this not replaced in the row but apparently replaced because retrieval always gets the replaced value. If you're going to access only a few rows it's an optimization, but if you're heavily using all rows it's a waste of effort. On SO we (who are helping you) don't ask questions for irrelevant reasons so please avoid "doesn't matter" answers

Comment: ps *"In one column there is a single word"* is a contraction of "in one of the columns, each of the rows bears a value that is a single word". I don't think anyone familiar with a datatable would read "In one column there is a single word" and think it was like some excel "merge and center" operation that merged 90k rows into a single cell bearing one word. As a sentence on its own it was clarifying that the "ColumnX" of your datatable contains row values that are just single words, not values that are sentences of multiple words (ony some words of which need replacimg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have your dictionary of replacements:

```
Dim d as New Dictionary(Of String, String)
d("foo") = "bar"
d("baz") = "buf"
```

You can apply them to your table's ReplaceMe column:

```
Dim rep as String = Nothing
For Each r as DataRow In dt.Rows
  If d.TryGetValue(r.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe"), rep) Then r("ReplaceMe") = rep 
Next r
```

On my machine it takes 340ms for 1 million replacements. I can cut that down to 260ms by using column number rather than name - `If d.TryGetValue(r.Field(Of String)(0), rep) Then r(0) = rep`

Timing:

```
    'setup, fill a dict with string replacements like "1" -> "11", "7" -> "17"
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For i = 0 To 9
        d(i.ToString()) = (i + 10).ToString()
    Next

    'put a million rows in a datatable, randomly assign dictionary keys as row values
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ReplaceMe")
    Dim r As New Random()
    Dim k = d.Keys.ToArray()
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        dt.Rows.Add(k(r.Next(k.Length)))
    Next

    'what range of values do we have in our dt?
    Dim minToMaxBefore = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Min(Function(ro) ro.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe")) & " - " & dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(ro) ro.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe"))

    'it's a crappy way to time, but it'll prove the point
    Dim start = DateTime.Now

    Dim rep As String = Nothing
    For Each ro As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If d.TryGetValue(ro.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe"), rep) Then ro("ReplaceMe") = rep
    Next

    Dim ennd = DateTime.Now

    'what range of values do we have now
    Dim minToMaxAfter = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Min(Function(ro) ro.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe")) & " - " & dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(ro) ro.Field(Of String)("ReplaceMe"))


    MessageBox.Show($"min to max before of {minToMaxBefore} became {minToMaxAfter} proving replacements occurred, it took {(ennd - start).TotalMilliseconds} ms for 1 million replacements")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this approach is incredibly (unbeleivably) fast!