# Responsibility of Domain Object

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design

I have a domain in which employees can have a list of roles..  There is a new role adding feature also..  While adding a new role, we need to check whether the employee already has a “VP” role. If it is already present new role should not be added. This logic need to be present in the Employee Domain entity.

I started it by adding a method name  `IsNewRoleAllowed()` which will return a Boolean.. If it is true, the business layer will insert the new role to database.

But to be more natural `OO`, I decided to change the Employee object’s responsibility by making a function `AddRole`.  Instead of returning the Boolean, it will perform the role adding responsibility.

I achieved the above by receiving an `Action<int, int>` as parameter. It is working fine.

**QUESTION**

Is it a correct practice to pass the DAL method to entity?

*UPDATE*

@ThomasWeller added to important points to which I agree...

> 1. Having a role is a pure concept of the BL. It has nothing to do with the DAL.
> 2. In this approach, the BL would have a dependency of code that resides in the DAL. It (BL) even should work when a DAL does not even physically exist.

But, since I am not using ORM, how would I modify the code to work like the suggested approach?

**REFERENCES**

1. [Grouping IDataRecord individual records to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699004/)

*CODE*

**Domain Entities**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    //Add Role to Employee
    public int AddRole(Role role, Action<int, int> insertMethod)
    {
        if (!Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == "VP"))
        {
            insertMethod(this.EmployeeID, role.RoleID);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -101;
        }
    }


    //IDataRecord Provides access to the column values within each row for a DataReader
    //IDataRecord is implemented by .NET Framework data providers that access relational databases.

    //Factory Method
    public static Employee EmployeeFactory(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = (int)record[0],
            EmployeeName = (string)record[1],
            Roles = new List<Role>()
        };

        employee.Roles.Add(new Role { RoleID = (int)record[2], RoleName = (string)record[3] });
        return employee;

    }
}
```

**BusinessLayer.Manager**

```
public class EmployeeBL
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = EmployeeRepositoryDAL.GetEmployees();
        return employees;
    }

    public void AddRoleToEmployee(Employee emp, Role role)
    {
        //Don't trust the incoming Employee object. Use only id from it
        Employee employee = EmployeeRepositoryDAL.GetEmployeeByID(emp.EmployeeID);
        employee.AddRole<Employee>(role, EmployeeRepositoryDAL.InsertEmployeeRole);
        //EmployeeRepositoryDAL.InsertEmployeeRole(emp.EmployeeID, role.RoleID);
    }
}
```

**DAL**

```
    public static void InsertEmployeeRole(int empID, int roleID)
    {
        string commandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeRole VALUES (@empID, @roleID)";

        List<SqlParameter> commandParameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
                                                {
                                                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@empID", 
                                                                      Value = empID, 
                                                                      SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
                                                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@roleID", 
                                                                      Value = roleID, 
                                                                      SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int}
                                                };


        CommonDAL.ExecuteNonQuery(commandText, commandParameters);

    }
```

Comment: Why would you need a generic param for your `AddRole` method at all - you never use it. So what?

Answer (score 1):

No. Having a role is a pure concept of the BL in the first place, it has nothing to do with the DAL. Also, in your approach, the BL would have a dependency of code that resides in the DAL, which would be the wrong direction. The BL should be *persistence agnostic* (i.e. it shouldn't depend in any way on something that would happen in the DAL - it even should work when a DAL does not even physically exist.). Furthermore, the responsibility of the DAL is only to *persist* objects - not to handle any collections that reside in memory.

Keep it as simple as possible, and just do:

```
public int AddRole(Role role)
{
    if (!Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == "VP"))
    {
        Roles.Add(role.RoleName);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -101;
    }
}
```

... in your `Employee` class, and let the DAL handle all persistence related questions (if you use an ORM it will do cascading updates anyway).

Comment: I totally agree to your points- `Having a role is a pure concept of the BL. It has nothing to do with the DAL. ` and
`In your approach, the BL would have a dependency of code that resides in the DAL. It (BL) even should work when a DAL does not even physically exist.`

But since I am not using `ORM`, how would I modify the code to work like this?

Comment: So if you're not using an ORM you will have to keep track of all modifications manually. Are you really sure that you want to do this?

Comment: I too feel that it is not practical to go for this goal without ORM... Since I am not going for ORM I will have to stay away from achieving these goals.. My code will not be testable.. But I feel my current approach is good to have the business logic inside the entity

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a correct practice to pass the DAL method to entity?

**I avoid injection of DAL logic into my Domain Model.**

It is not needed to update Data Base once Domain Entity (e.g. `Employee`) is updated.

The common solution is:

1. Load entities to update from DB into memory ([Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html), PoEAA).
2. Create/ update/ delete entities in memory
3. Save all changes into DB

**In order to track new/dirty/deleted entities [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern**

[image: Unit of Work]

**is used usually:**

- [The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)
- [Unit of Work and Repository Design Pattern Implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/unit-of-work-and-repository-design-pattern-implementation)

Comment: I am not using any ORM... IS your answer specific to ORM?

Comment: No, it is not specific to ORM. ORMs provide this functionality for you out of the box. If you do not use any ORM then you can implement all these patterns by yourself.

Comment: Can you suggest any blog/article that will completely demonstrate a UoW with Employee-Role domain and is easy to understand... I have updated the question... Could you please update your answer with these details?