# Check if a string of substring of it exists in datatable

Tags: c#, string, datatable

I have a datatable like this:

```
    column1     column2
    --------------------
   1  12345       John
   2  123         Jane
   3  1236        Sam
   4  23457       Sarah
```

I want to check if a string or substring of it **from the left side**, exists in this datatable. 
For example if 123678 is the string I'm looking for, record 3 should be returned (although record 2 is also a match, record 3 has more common characters). And if I'm looking for 345789, nothing should be returned (although record 4 has 4 common characters, they are different in the first one).

Currently I'm using the code below, but I think it could be enhanced. Any idea?

```
public int? FindStr (string input)
    {
        maxLenDt = Dt.Compute("Max(column1)", "").ToString().Length;
        minLenDt = Dt.Compute("Min(column1)", "").ToString().Length;

        int lc = maxLenDt > input.Length ? input.Length : maxLenDt;
        for (int i = lc; i >= minLenDt; i--)
        {
            string code = input.Substring(0,i);
            var dw = Dt.Select("column1  = " + code );
            if (dw.Length > 0)
            {
               //return row
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can find the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836037/datatable-select-method

Comment: @Suhail Keyjani, thank you but this is not the answer. I'm not searching table for a fixed search text.

Comment: Cycle through Dt.Rows by yourself and use a Linq query. You can than do a correct comparison with the column values length.