# Fetch an attribute from database corresponding to maximum attribute

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have to get `bill_version` from my table `reports` where the bill number is maximum
**(There can be multiple bill numbers with same value but categorized by their `bill_version`)**

I'm a newbie to C# and do not know the appropriate syntax regarding the same. So far I'm able to get the maximum bill number in the variable `maxBillNumber`. I do not want to run another query for getting that bill version. How can modify this code according to my need?

Here's the code:

```
int maxBillNumber =0;
if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
     {
         int bill_number1 = dr.Field<int>("bill_number");
         maxBillNumber = Math.Max(maxBillNumber, bill_number1);
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
 I have to get maximum value of another column `bill_version` corresponding to that maximum row containing `bill_number` without running another query.

```
bill_number  bill_version  
1            0  
2            0  
3            0  
4            1  
4            2  
4            3
```

I have fetched **4** already. Now I have to get that corresponding **3**

Comment: `int maxBillNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Compute("max(bill_number)", string.Empty));`

Comment: Try and do research before you ask questions. I am going to close this as a duplicate, let me know if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I guess you **misunderstood** my question. I have fetched the maximum value, you can see the above code for that. Now **I have to get value of another column corresponding to that maximum row without running another query.** @JeremyThompson

Comment: Ok just google **C# DataTable Select**   `DataRow[] result = dt1.Select("bill_number = " + maxBillNumber);
        foreach (DataRow row in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]);
        }` Because the data is all in memory as a DataTable this code isn't another query.

Comment: Sorry I did misunderstand but this is a duplicate of over a hundred questions other so my advice to **research before asking still stands**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836037/datatable-select-method

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link though :) I'll research more next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("BillNumber", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("BillVersion", typeof(int));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(1, 0);
        table.Rows.Add(2, 0);
        table.Rows.Add(3, 0);
        table.Rows.Add(4, 1);
        table.Rows.Add(4, 2);
        table.Rows.Add(4, 3);
        var dataRows = table.AsEnumerable().ToList();

        var result = dataRows.OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemArray[0]).ThenByDescending(x => x.ItemArray[1]).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(result.ItemArray[1].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxBillNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Compute("max([bill_number])", string.Empty));

DataRow[] result = dt1.Select("bill_number = " + maxBillNumber); 
foreach (DataRow row in result) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]); 
}
```